How to check if the input includes an object called 'name' in a class collected in a list? Python
I'm making a program where you can make a city and I want it so that if you type info and then the building name which is an argument in a class. The buildings and roads created are in 2 separate lists.
Is there any way to use an 'if' or 'elif' statement to check if the name typed after 'info' is the name argument defined with user input in any of the building or road classes in the list.
So in a brief summary, if you're confused with my question, I have 2 lists. Buildings and roads. You can add either the road class or the building class depending on the list with a given input. Now I want to check if the user input is info building name (Imagine that 'building name' is the name argument in the class you added to that list) so that the info function in each class will do its thing and give details about the specific building or road as given in the code.
Here's the program:
from math import pi
from random import randint as rd


class building():
    popularity = rd(1,20)
    was_reset = False

    def __init__(self,name,shape,window_amount,radius,height,width,perpendicular_height,base_area,end_area):
        self.name = name
        self.shape = shape
        self.window_amount = window_amount
        
        self.popularity = rd(1,20)
        
        self.radius: int = radius
        self.height: int = height
        self.width: int = width
        self.perpendicular_height: int = perpendicular_height
        self.base_area: int = base_area
        self.end_area: int = end_area
        
        if not str(self.name):
            print('\nError! Name must be a word or phrase. Not a number!\n')
        elif not str(self.shape):
            print('\nError! Shape must not be a number.\n')
        elif not int(self.window_amount):
            print('\nError! Amount of windows must be a number.\n')
        
        if (self.shape).lower() == 'sphere':
            self.radius = int(input('\nRadius: \n'))
            self.volume = (4/3)*(pi*building.radius)^3
        elif (self.shape).lower() == 'pyramid':
            self.base_area = int(input('\nArea of Base: '))
            self.perpendicular_height = int(input('\nPerpendicular Height: '))

            self.volume = (1/3)*(building.base_area)*(building.perpendicular_height)
        elif (self.shape).lower() == 'cone':
            self.base_area = int(input('\nArea of Base: '))
            self.perpendicular_height = int(input('\nPerpendicular Height: '))

            self.volume = (1/3)*(building.base_area)*(building.perpendicular_height)
        elif (self.shape).lower() == 'cylinder':
            self.perpendicular_height = int(input('\nPerpendicular Height: '))
            self.radius = int(input('\nRadius: \n'))

            self.volume = ((pi*building.radius)^2)*building.perpendicular_height
        elif (self.shape).lower() == 'prism':
            self.end_area = int(input('\nArea of End: '))
            self.perpendicular_height = int(input('\nPerpendicular Height: \n'))

            self.volume = building.end_area * building.perpendicular_height
        else:
            print(f'Error! {self.shape} is not a valid shape.')
    
    def info(self):
        return f'Volume: {self.volume}\nName: {self.name}\nWindow Amount: {self.window_amount}'
            
    
    def enhance(self):
        enhancement = rd(1,20)
        self.popularity += enhancement
    
class road():
    def __init__(self,name,type_,length,speed_limit):
        self.name = name
        self.type_ = type_
        self.length = length
        self.speed_limit = speed_limit

        if not str(self.name):
            print('\nError! Name must be a word or phrase. Not a number!\n')
        elif not str(self.type_):
            print('\nError! Type of road must be a word or phrase. Not a number!\n')
        elif not int(self.length):
            print('\nError! Length must be a number.\n')
        elif not int(self.speed_limit):
            print('\nError! Speed limit must be a number.\n')
        
        if (self.type).lower() != 'highway' or (self.type).lower() != 'expressway' or (self.type).lower() != 'express way' or (self.type).lower() != 'regular':
            if (self.type).lower() != 'fork':
                print(f'Error! {self.type_} is not a type of road. Try something like highway or fork.')
            else:
                name1 = str(input('\nName of Seperate Road 1: '))
                type1 = str(input('\nType of Seperate Road 1: '))
                length1 = str(input('\nLength of Seperate Road 1: '))
                speed_limit1 = int(input('\nSpeed Limit of Seperate road 1: \n'))

                name2 = str(input('\nName of Seperate Road 2: '))
                type2 = str(input('\nType of Seperate Road 2: '))
                length2 = str(input('\nLength of Seperate Road 2: '))
                speed_limit2 = int(input('\nSpeed Limit of Seperate road 2: \n'))

                self.split_road = [road(name1,type1,length1,speed_limit1),road(name2,type2,length2,speed_limit2)]
        
    def info(self):
        return f'Name: {self.name}\nRoad Type: {self.type_}\nLength: {self.length}\nSpeed Limit: {self.speed_limit}'

buildings = []
roads = []

print('\nHello! Welcome to CityScape, where gamer-made civilisations thrive! To start, type building to make a building\nand road to make a road! Type info then the name of a building/road to get the\ninfo about said building/road!\n')

while True:
    user_input = input('>> ')

    if user_input == 'building':
        building_name = input('Building Name: ')
        building_shape = input('Building Shape: ')
        building_windows = input('Amount of Windows: ')

        if building_shape.lower() == 'sphere':
            buildings.append(building(building_name,building_shape,building_windows,self.radius,0,0,0,0,0))
        
        if building_shape.lower() == 'pyramid':
            buildings.append(building(building_name,building_shape,building_windows,0,0,0,self.perpendicular_height,self.base_area,0))
        
        if building_shape.lower() == 'cone':
            buildings.append(building(building_name,building_shape,building_windows,0,0,0,self.perpendicular_height,self.base_area,0))
        
        if building_shape.lower() == 'cylinder':
            buildings.append(building(building_name,building_shape,building_windows,self.radius,0,0,self.perpendicular_height,0,0))
        
        if building_shape.lower() == 'prism':
            buildings.append(building(building_name,building_shape,building_windows,0,0,0,self.perpendicular_height,0,self.end_area))
    elif user_input == 'road':
        road_name = input('Road Name: ')
        road_type = input('Road Type: ')
        road_length = input('Road Length: ')
        road_speedlimit = input('Speed Limit: ')

        roads.append(road(road_name,road_type,road_length,road_speedlimit))



I'm not sure I understand your question, but you might be looking for hasattr(buildings[0], 'radius')

You probably want to raise a ValueError in the event that your input is bad. Otherwise your instance gets created with bad data.

Most of your setting of attribute values is at the class level and you probably don't want to reset them every time you instantiate a new building. For example you probably don't want to do building.radius = int(input('\nRadius: \n')) rather self.radius = int(input('\nRadius: \n'))

You might also want to rename your class from building() to Building() as that is a more conventional casing for class names.

If you want to ensure than items have unique names or quickly find an item by name, you might want to look at changing buildings from a list of Building() to a dictionary with keys of name and values of Building().
## ----------------------
## Since we are keen to ensure than two buildings don't share a name
## let's build a dictionary with key of name
## ----------------------
#buildings = []
buildings = {}
## ----------------------

Then in your while loop you might...
    if user_input == 'building':
        building_name = input('Building Name: ')
        if building_name in buildings:
            print(f"The building name \"{building_name}\" is already in use.")
            continue

        building_shape = input('Building Shape: ')
        building_windows = input('Amount of Windows: ')
        buildings[building_name] = building(building_name,building_shape,building_windows)


you can filter your list to check for any buildings with the name given like this
filtered_buildings = list(filter(lambda x: x.name=="building name",buildings))
filtered_roads= list(filter(lambda x: x.name=="road name",roads))

if len(filtered_buildings):
    # building stuff here
elif len(filtered_roads):
    # road stuff here

as a side note, may i point you to __repr__ and __str__ as possible replacements for your info method (see also this post)
